# Shared config possible using Spring cloud consul config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-consul

We're using Spring Cloud Consul Config 1.3-RELEASE on Java 8 for simple app helloworldclient, works as expected with `bootstrap.xml`...

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      token: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        register: true
        service-name: helloworldclient-xyz123
        health-check-url: ${HEALTH_CHECK_URL}
      config:
        profile-separator: '/'
        enabled: true
        format: yaml
      host: ${CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR}
      port: 8500
  application:
    name: helloworldclient
```

Running the app with profile `dev`, this is the loaded config from `/env`...

```
    "consul:config/helloworldclient/dev/": {
       "product[0].sku": "BL394D",
       "product[0].quantity": 8 
    }
```

All that is fine, but we're not sure why the remaining consul config sections are even present, and what they're used for:

```
  "consul:config/application/dev/": {},
  "consul:config/application/": {},
```

This is interesting because we have a requirement for shared config such that multiple applications have a way load common, environment-specific config from consul, if possible; some questions to determine if this is a viable solution:

**Questions**

- Is SCC attempting to read from those locations in addition to the application config path?
- Is the default folder `config/application` configurable such that on startup the app reads from `config/mysharedconfig` instead?
- Is it suitable to use `/config/application/dev` as a shared config location where multiple applications can load common, environment-specific config?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question:

Based on [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-consul/1.3.0.RELEASE/multi/multi_spring-cloud-consul-config.html) -- and some quick tests -- Consul supports shared properties via `spring.cloud.consul.config.defaultContext`, which by default is set to `application`, effectively loading config from `consul:config/application`, `consul:config/application/dev`, etc., on startup (in addition to config for the app, of course). And `defaultContext` is customizable, so we changed it to `commoncfg` then granted all ACL tokens permission to read from that location. You don't need to bother with ACL tokens unless you're using them, I only mention it because we use tokens and this step was necessary.

spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      config:
        defaultContext: commoncfg